# witadmin exportprocessconfig command give error TF400572

Tags: tfs

On one project on TFS2013, I give the error TF400572 when I try to export process config (with witadmin command).
This project was initialized (with older version of TFS, 2010 or 2012) with a custom process template (I think).

My goal is to edit this process. What can I do ?

Command run :

```
witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://blablabla:8080/bla/bla /p:blablabla /f:c:\process.xml
```

And the error is : TF400572: The Project Process Settings must be configured for this feature to be used.

Comment: Whats the exact error message, and exact command you're executing?

Comment: As it is already given answer in msdn forums [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eddf093e-d2ee-46ec-b52a-3f0c131e140b/tf400572-the-common-project-settings-and-the-agile-project-settings-must-be-configured-for-this?forum=tfsprocess), this is because while upgrading from TFS 2012, some configuration files are combined.

You can find the detailed information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx). Did you tried this solution?

Comment: @BeytanKurt, the page you mention explain the workflow the follow after a migration of TFS (export process, modify process and import process). But nothing if the export process fail, which is my case.

Comment: Yes but I think, your problem is the result of the given situation. Just mentioned it, maybe it'll be useful to you.